# web.config one connection string for both DbContext and ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, dbcontext, objectcontext

In my project, I have upgrade some of the business to `DbContext`, previous version was on `ObjectContext`.
I want to have one `ConnectionString` in `web.config` for both `DbContext` and `ObjectContext`.

```
<add name="OjContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=server-pc;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="DbContext" connectionString="Data Source=server-pc;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;password=123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Short answer, you can't.. they are not the same and thus will cause issues if you try to share them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to build your "OjContext" connection object in your code, using the "DbContext" connection string for `EntityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString` property.

See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb738533(v=VS.100).aspx